# Download failed because the resources could not be found

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

Obb files download in my projects stopped working recently for all my *unpublished* applications. The error string is in the topic. But it works for *published* applications (that may be the clue)!

My device is Nexus 7 (2012), I upgraded it to 4.4.2 recently (that may be another clue).

The error comes from class    **com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl**

```
public void applicationError(int errorCode)
```

is called with `errorCode 3`. I wonder if anybody knows what it means.

Any suggestions how to make obb files download work are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

errorCode 3 means that the downloaded file don't comes from the market.

You probably need to check the "Allow installation of apps from unknown sources" in device security settings.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! The option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider when the device is not downloading the expansion files.

You can read more about testing the expansion file downloads [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Testing).

1. Make sure the application you want to test has been published in the developer's console. It will take a few hours to publish once you have done this, so you might want to publish the day before you test. You can publish to alpha while testing so you don't have to release it to the market in order to test.
2. Make sure you're logged into the device using an account that is registered as a tester of the app.
3. Make sure that your device is listed in the list of approved devices on the developer's console. I think all devices are approved by default.
4. Make sure that the version number of the expansion file that you have listed on the test app is the same version number that is on the developer's console itself.
5. This may not be required, but if you haven't published the app to the store, make sure that you're using a build with the same signature as the app on the developer's console.

From my experience, it's some combination of these that are giving you an issue.

Comment: I have a published app with its expansion file uploaded. I am testing the expansion file downloading part using the apk installed via Android Studio (and not from the Market). It should work right? Signature and version are same?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue while testing APK expansion files. My mistake copied files from the downloader_library sample and didn't change file sizes.

```
  private static final XAPKFile[] xAPKS = {
        new XAPKFile(
                true, // main file
                1, // APK version
                7157821 // file size in bytes (was mistaken here)
        ), new XAPKFile(
        false, // patch file
        1, // APK  version
        891598// length of patch file
        )
};
```